# Getting Processor Hardware Name of android device

Tags: android

I execute `/proc/cpuinfo` to get the details of CPU in android device using the below code.

```
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/cpuinfo");
            InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
            TextView tv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(getStringFromInputStream(is));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "------ getCpuInfo " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Within this it also returns Hardware Name. The Hardware name which I get is not in proper readable Format.  I have tested this in various devices like Samsung Note 3, Micromax Canvas Doodle A111, Micromax Turbo A250.

This is what I get in these devices respectively:

- *Samsung EXYNOS5420* : (but I need this name ***Samsung Exynos Octa 5420*** )
- *QRD MSM8625Q EVBD*  : (need name ***Qualcomm Snapdragon 200*** )
- *MT6589*             : ( ***MediaTek MT6589*** )

How can I overcome this, Please Help !!!

Comment: Can you tell me what details you see in this app :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dama.hardwareinfo&hl=en

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bit unclear to me if that you CPU capabilities or device information in general, but anyway...

Android provides a nice little class called [Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) which gets you quite a bit of information directly via the static fields of the class. This class provides a lot of device-level information as shown below:

Taken directly from my HTC One M8 (some fields omitted):

```
Build.BOARD: MSM8974
Build.BOOTLOADER: 3.19.0.0000
Build.BRAND: htc
Build.DEVICE: htc_m8
Build.DISPLAY: cm_m8-userdebug 5.1.1 LMY47V 47d6aee9c3 test-keys
Build.HARDWARE: qcom
Build.MANUFACTURER: htc
Build.MODEL: One M8
Build.PRODUCT: cm_m8
```

From the looks of it `Build.BRAND + " " + Build.MODEL` looks like what you want.

Whilst the docs doesn't guarantee any standardization for any field, this is likely to be better than calling `Runtime.exec("cat /proc/cpuinfo")` and parsing from there.

If CPU level capabilities is what you want, you can try doing from native code using android cpufeatures library, calling the function:

```
uint64_t android_getCpuFeatures();
```

to get a int containing many CPU feature flags.

Comment: Thanks, Could u pls explain me more about using native code, I have never done native programming !

Comment: @vivekwarde Go look at tutorials on Android NDK. The conventions are similar to JNI but android provides it's own build tools.