# How to programmatically determine if phone has 5G hardware capability?

Tags: android, cellular-network, 5g

I'm trying to find out programmatically if a phone is capable of a 5G connection. Is there a way to fetch the list shown under [Mobile Network- Network Modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTszc.png)?

- I'm able to programmatically determine if the phone is *currently* on a 5G connection or not
- I.E. If the phone is a S20 5G Ultra, but set to LTE only mode, but the hardware could connect to a 5G band.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61066013/detect-5g-connection-on-android-phone) can relate

Comment: @Zain I already know how to tell if a phone is on a 5G connection (as your link shows), I want to know if the phone is NOT on a 5G connection but is capable of 5G.

Comment: @AlvinFong i want to know the same. Were you able to find out a conclusive way for this? Google search doesn't really help as most of the result shows what the device is connected to not really what it is capable of connecting to

Comment: @iOSer I never did come to a satisfactory answer. If I were to do it again today, I think the most reliable way would be to get the processor hardware name (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122959/getting-processor-hardware-name-of-android-device), then reference a list of 5g-enabled chips.

Comment: ah @AlvinFong Thanks for the update. I think this sort of detection cannot be done on hardware level. Ive pushed back to the product team asked them to consider user input as the source of truth, if he chooses wrong then his fault :D. 

Thanks for your help